# How to fix Flutter doctor error at Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, android-studio-4.1

I am trying to fix error from the flutter doctor -v command and i have no idea what the error is now.

It recognizes Android Studio and even though the flutter and dart plugins are installed, it says they **can be installed**. Is it not finding them? The message is highlighted green, so i guess it doesn't matter too much. But in the next part it says flutter doctor check crashed and gives a path error for a weirdly formatted android studio plugins path? I set the android studio path with "flutter config --android-studio-dir [/path/to/android/studio]" and the sdk with "flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk" and apparently it recognized android studio. What exactly is its problem here?

Thanks in advance to everyone trying to help!

Here is part of the terminal output:

```
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at D:\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[☠] Android Studio (the doctor check crashed)
    X Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.     
    X FileSystemException: Exists failed, path = 'D:\Android\Android Studio" .plugins' (OS Error: Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist
      falsch.
      , errno = 123)
    • #0      _Directory.existsSync (dart:io/directory_impl.dart:94:7)
      #1      ForwardingFileSystemEntity.existsSync (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_file_system_entity.dart:43:33)
      #2      ErrorHandlingDirectory.existsSync.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:479:22)
      #3      _runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:573:14)
      #4      ErrorHandlingDirectory.existsSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:478:12)
      #5      AndroidStudio.pluginsPath (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:186:52)
      #6      AndroidStudioValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio_validator.dart:46:17)
      #7      asyncGuard.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:111:32)
      #8      asyncGuard.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:109:18)
      #9      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1354:13)
      #10     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
      #11     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1789:10)
      #12     runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1777:12)
      #13     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1708:12)
      #14     asyncGuard (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:109:3)
      #15     Doctor.startValidatorTasks (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:199:9)
      #16     Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:303:47)
      #17     DoctorCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:50:47)
      #18     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1192:12)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #19     FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1043:27)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #20     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #21     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:196:13)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #22     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #23     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #24     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:232:5)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #25     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #26     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #27     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
      <asynchronous suspension>


[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.2)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Users\Marcel\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\202.6397.94
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.3)
    • IntelliJ at G:\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
```

Comment: I had the same issue, solved with following https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83195
and running this command (the catch was in the double quotes for me)
`flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"`

Answer (score 4):

Accordingly to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83195
it should be possible to solve the issue by setting the path to Android Studio.

I could solve the issue with `flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"`

Comment: For me *setting* this value caused the error.  I used tab completion and it gave me the path in single quotes with a trailing slash.  Repeating the command without the trailing slash and wrapping in double quotes fixed it.